# ANDROID_HOME not overriding local.properties

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I have a local.properties file in my git repo for an Android project.  On my build server it is checking out git and running gradle targets to execute unit tests.  The build server is linux and I'm on a mac so where the Android SDK is installed is different, I could change but don't want to.

Does ANDROID_HOME override local.properties; can't tell if I'm setting environment variable correctly in Jenkins (Build Server) or if local.properties beats env variable.

Source I've been reading is: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

> Note: You will also need a local.properties file to set the location of the SDK in the same way that the existing SDK requires, using the sdk.dir property.
>   Alternatively, you can set an environment variable called ANDROID_HOME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most tools I've seen, a local configuration will override environment variables.

From a jenkins perspective, using environment variables makes sense as they can be propagated to multiple projects.

Comment: I've gotten it to work with Environment variables and have removed the local.properties file from git. Your answer is correct.